# C# POSTing [FromBody] data from one controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to send `[FromBody]` POST data to a controller using `client.GetAsync()` (or PostAsync/SendAsync?

I had to set up a base controller that all api calls will go through.

My ajax calls all go to this `SecureApi` controller, and they send the original path as a parameter to that they can be re-routed to the correct controller. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./api/SecureApi/?path=/api/OtherApi/SomeRoute",
    data: {
        param1: 1,
        param2: 2
    }
});
```

So my base controller looks something like:

```
public class SecurityApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SecureApi([FromBody]object data, string path)
    {
        // do some stuff

        // get uri
        var applicationPath = Request.RequestUri.Scheme + "://" + Request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.Replace("/", String.Empty);
        Uri routeUri = new Uri(applicationPath + path);

        // then redirect to correct controller
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var server = new HttpServer(config);
        var client = new HttpClient(server);
        // how can I send [FromBody]object data here?
        var response = client.GetAsync(routeUri).Result; // or PostAsync/SendAsync?
        return response;
    }
}
```

The `other` controller looks like:

```
public class OtherApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage OtherApi([FromBody]OtherData data)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't change `OtherApi`, so I HAVE to send the `[FromBody]` POST data in the same way (in the POST body).

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**

Per @Philippe's response below, I'm using PostAsJsonAsync and it seems to want to work, but I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized result. More info:

I went with the correct(?) ASYNC/AWAIT route...

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SecureApi([FromBody]Dictionary<string, dynamic> data, string path)
{
    ...
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(routePath, data);
    return response;
}
```

And the `Other` controller has:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] // I do have the "Admin" role
[Route("Save")]
[HttpPost]
public SaveResultBase Save([FromBody]Dictionary<string, dynamic> data)
{
    ...
}
```

But this controller is never hit (no breakpoints are hit there) and it returns a 401 Unauthorized response.

I guess that I have to add my user credentials to the client headers before calling `PostAsJsonAsync`. Can't find any way to do that though.

Answer (score 2):

The method GetAsync of HttpClient will send a HTTP GET request so it would only be possible to have `[FromUri]` arguments. Because `[FromBody]` argument are by definition POST data, you will want to use `PostAsJsonAsync`/ `PostAsXmlAsync`/`PostAsync`. The difference between all of them is how the data is serialized.

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(routeUri, data).Result;
```

That being said, if you have security in mind, it would be rather easy for anyone to call the "right api" directly. Moreover you will increase latency by generating two HTTP requests.

You should take a look at [this guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security) on MSDN. I believe that an [authentication filter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! We do use user authentication and auth filtering, but we want to be able to use AES encryption on our standard API calls, so that it's not easily exposed to the user. Not sure this is the best way, but it's what we came up with. Definitely up for other suggestions though. (I'm about to try PostAsJsonAsync and will mark this as the "answer" when I get it working).

Comment: I've added more info up top  under "EDIT"

Comment: @dmathisen The main issue with this implementation is that you either block the routing to your other APIs so that you are sure they can't be called directly (but in this case you are blocking your own connections as well) or that you let the standard routing (and the secure API becomes useless as anyone can get the direct address by looking at the URL). Regarding your 401 errors, I'm pretty sure you have this issue because the server doesn't  consider the SecureAPI as the same user than the "real" client... There might be a way to set the cookie container of the HTTPClient from the client...